# nhibernate activerecord linq Contains problem

Tags: linq, nhibernate, activerecord, contains

I am having problems with the following query in Castle ActiveRecord 2.12:

```
var q = from o in SodisceFMClientVAR.Queryable
        where taxnos2.Contains(o.TaxFileNo)
        select o;
```

taxNos2 is an array of strings.

When run I get an exception:
+

> InnerException    {"Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less
>   than the size of the
>   collection.\r\nParameter name:
>   index"}   System.Exception
>   {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
>
> ```
>   StackTrace  "   at
> ```
>
> Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.ExecuteQuery(IActiveRecordQuery
>   query)\r\n   at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq.LinqResultWrapper`1.Populate()\r\n
>   at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq.LinqResultWrapper`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>   at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   source)\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)\r\n   at
>   prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataAccess.InsolventnostDataAccAR.GetOurUsersListLS(ICollection`1
>   taxNos) in
>   C:\\svn\\skb\\insolventnostWithAR\\prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataAccess\\InsolventnostDataAR.cs:line
>   214\r\n   at
>   prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataFromWS.InsolventnostFromWS.filterByOurUsers(IEnumerable`1
>   odprtiPostopki) in
>   C:\svn\skb\insolventnostWithAR\prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataFromWS\InsolventnostFromWS.cs:line
>   237\r\n   at
>   prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataFromWS.InsolventnostFromWS.SyncData()
>   in
>   C:\svn\skb\insolventnostWithAR\prosoft.skb.insolventnostDataFromWS\InsolventnostFromWS.cs:line
>   53"   string

Does Contains even work in linq for nhibernate? I couldn't find anything via google... 
Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about Castle ActiveRecord, but I know Contains() works in LINQ-to-NHibernate.

Comment: How are you mapping taxnos2? Can you show your mapping attribute for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out - the problem was actually in the class mapping to the table, DateTime fields needed to be DateTime ? fields.

Weird error though...